# How can I prevent tapjacking in Android without breaking legitimate use of overlays?

Tags: java, android, android-security

I am trying to prevent tapjacking in my app. I have read that the typical way to do this is to set `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured=true` in every view. However, from what I understand this would also prevent touches from working when the user has some legitimate overlay in use such as Facebook Messenger or a blue light filter app. What is the best practice for preventing tapjacking without breaking any use of overlays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there does not seem to be a way to prevent tapjacking without breaking some blue light filters. However many bluelight filters on more recent versions of Android seem to be using the blue light filter in Settings via accessibility. These apps will continue to work, so `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured=true` will only break the app when some bluelight filters are used, not all.